# I have problem with fetching data in JSX react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, jsx

I want to get data from swapi and do jsx component with this data, but react give me a error when i want to use this data 
This my fetch

```
var promise = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/')
  .then((res) =>  res.json() )
  .then(data => setLuke(data.data))
```

And this is react error:

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**
i dont know what to do 
can you help me with this little problem

Comment: show your render.. Probably you are just rendering promisee ?

Comment: const Main =  async() => {
  const [luke, setLuke] = useState()
  var req = async () => {
    var promise = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/').then((res) =>  res.json() ).then(data => setLuke(data.data)) 
    console.log(luke)
         }
      useEffect(() => req())
 return  (<>
 {luke}
 </>)
}

Comment: Your `data.data` from the response is probably an object.

Comment: You `Main` is async. And hope you are rendering main.. so it is a promise. You should remove the async in Main and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably rendering your promise var instead of {luke}. Also note that **data** will be a json object so you won't be able to render it directly. You will need to stringify it first. **data.data** which you are currently using will also be undefined. Just use data, it already contains the json.

```
await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setLuke(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
```

You should then be able to render it using `{luke}`